# XSS attacks: change exception thrown in a Spring Boot CRUDRepository ?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, xss

I'm developing an API for an application that is able to find so-called ProductSolutions based on their solutionID (which is an integer).

The code looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductSolutionRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductSolution, String> {

    public List<ProductSolution> findBySolutionId(@Param("solutionId") int solutionId);
}
```

When sending a request with a string instead of an integer (`localhost:8080/api/v1/productSolutions/search/findBySolutionId?solutionId=dangerousscript`)the API returns an error with the following message:

> Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param int] for value
>   'dangerousscript'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   \"dangerousscript\""`

Although it appears that Chrome and Firefox are neatly escaping the input (and don't execute any scripts) people are still afraid our API might be used for cross site scripting attacks.

A simple way to fix this would be removing the input the user gave when we throw an exception, or make our own error page. In what way can I configure spring boot to throw a custom exception?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with cross-site scripting though. It's just that you're trying to send a string where Spring expects an integer, and properly returns an exception. I don't see how exactly that would be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a method with `@ExceptionHandler` in class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`.

You can either annotate this method with `@ResponseBody` (if you're not using `@RestController`) and directly return desired response or rethrow exception with correct message.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(NumberFormatException.class)
    public ErrorResponse handleSearchParseException(NumberFormatException exception) {
       // do whathever you want
   }

}
```